# Space tab mystery, in git vs vim

Tags: bash, git, ubuntu, vim

I am on Ubuntu and use Gvim. Based on my understanding,I have set tab to expand to 4 spaces. I did not even touch the line that has `create_namespace` but `git diff` shows it as shifted by a character. It seems perfectly fine in the editor or when I run `cat`. Same issue is when I added a new line of txt `cluster_token` and it shows as shifted by a character in `git diff`. I have wasted hours trying to understand this silly issue but no clue. What is the issue and how do I fix it?

```
-       echo "--create_namespace"
+        echo "--create_namespace" //Did not even touch this line
        echo "--all"
        echo "--custom_merge_pipeline_commands"
+        echo "--cluster_token" //Looks fine in editor
```

Comment: Those lines were probably changed from tabs to spaces. The default visualization will make Git indent at column 4 first, so the first tab would only be 3 characters wide. When the tab is then replaced by spaces, those spaces (of course) take up real spaces that will not be condensed.

Comment: so what command should I used to turn it off temporarily? `set noexpandtab`? I am not sure why the characters are shifted by one extra to right still from your explanation. Is it like `\t` counts for one character and `4 spaces due to tab I pressed` count for 4 and hence total 5?

Comment: Try doing `git config --global core.pager "less -x1,5"`. That should set up the pager that `git diff` uses to indent it properly despite that leading `+/-`.

Comment: Note that this entire issue leads to space-vs-tab wars in some communities... :-) In vim, you can have tab-indent and space-indent displayed visually-differently (and yet get to the same columns) in various ways: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/422

Comment: I understand conceptually what "expanding tab to 4 spaces mean". But still apart from all the help I got above, I am totally not clear what is the issue in my scenario and what is git trying to display. Only if someone can explain a little more to me, at least I can connect the dots. I have already spent like 3 hours on this.

Comment: Tab rendering and translation is as fraught as crlf and case sensitivity.  What exact settings are you using?  You're probably best off with `:set sts=4 ts=8 et`, keeping hard tabs setting hard tabstops at anything but 8 is a recipe for later pain in large doses, `ts=8 et` is belt-and-suspenders, use only spaces except where some code that cares about the difference is reading them, like makefiles.

Comment: Does `git diff -w` help?

Answer (score 4):

If this is TL;DR, skip down to the bolded text below.

As I noted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812523/space-tab-mystery-in-git-vs-vim#comment90580612_51812523), the issue of spaces vs tabs sets off flame wars, so I'm going to attempt to be completely neutral on the subject.  (Note: I did say *attempt*. :-) )  It's also worth covering a bit of history, i.e., how we got here in the first place.  Also, there is an entirely separate, though currently beta, StackExchange web site devoted to vi / vim at https://vi.stackexchange.com/ so I am not going to get into the many vim settings available here.

First, note that tabs go back to the days of mechanical typewriters (well, probably even *before* then).

[image: mechanical typewriter]

Different models had different features, but most had a key labeled <kbd>TAB</kbd> that, when pressed, caused the [platen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platen)—the rubber roller that holds the paper—to slide leftward (assuming a Western-style, left-to-right carriage typewriter) from its current position to the next *tab stop*.  Tab stops were set mechanically, since all of this was run by wires and springs.  Since the type bars would always strike the paper at the center where the ribbon was held against the paper, sliding the platen leftward has the effect of making the next character come out somewhere to the right.  How *far* to the right, depends on the current column and, of course, the tab stop settings.

Early computer interfaces used or emulated mechanical typewriters—well, more precisely, [teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Hard-copy_terminals) interrfaces—sometimes complete with the exact same mechanically-controlled tab stops.  When [glass ttys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Early_VDUs) came out, they tended to emulate the existing TTYs.  Over time, the terminals got smarter, to the point where some had software-adjustable tab stops.

Others, however, limited tab stops in software to simply "every N columns", where N was variable.  DEC chose 10 for some of their early systems, but 8 proved more popular and became the default.  Here, sending an ASCII <kbd>TAB</kbd> (code 9 decimal) byte to the display terminal caused the terminal to move the cursor from whichever column it was in now, to one up-to-but-not-exceeding N (usually 8) characters to the right.  (The behavior of a cursor close to the end of the physical screen line varied, and still varies in software emulations, but the VT100 behavior is pretty common now.)

We no longer use any of these bits of hardware—at least, [not commonly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrocomputing)—but we do *emulate* them.  Pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key in an editor tends to move the cursor to "the next tab stop", wherever that may be.  Terminal emulators will emulate whatever terminal—often, again, the VT100, which has variable tab stops (set via escape sequences) but defaults to every eighth column (columns 9, 17, 25, and so on, if we number the first column 1—as is traditional—instead of the proper mathematical column zero :-) ).

For storing text in *files*, however, there is an option: we can store the literal ASCII <kbd>TAB</kbd> character (or the Unicode equivalent which is U+0009), or we can store however many *spaces* it might take to *get* to the selected column.  If we store a literal <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it is up to whatever it is that *displays* the file to choose *which column is the desired column*.  If we store literal space characters, whatever is displaying the file must display that many space characters.<sup>1</sup>  **The effect is that if we store literal <kbd>TAB</kbd>s, the display depends on previous output (since the cursor column depends on previous output), but if we store literal spaces, it does not.**

Meanwhile, **when `git diff` displays lines, it inserts one character in front of each line.**  If the line being displayed starts with a literal <kbd>TAB</kbd> followed by the word `old`, what happens is that `git diff` writes a space or plus or minus character, then a <kbd>TAB</kbd>, then the next character.  Assuming your terminal has its tab-stops at columns 9, 17, 25, and so on, the character after the <kbd>TAB</kbd> shows up in column 9:

```
0        1
1234567890123456789
-       old
```

If, on the other hand, the line in the file starts with eight spaces followed by the word `new`, what you see is the `git diff` character, then eight spaces, then the word in column 10:

```
0        1
1234567890123456789
+        new
```

Stacking these atop one another we get:

```
0        1
1234567890123456789
-       old
+        new
```

which is what you are seeing.  This means that your claim:

> ```
> -       echo "--create_namespace"
> +        echo "--create_namespace" //Did not even touch this line
> ```

is at best half-true: *you* might not have touched the line, but your *editor* did.  It replaced at least one literal <kbd>TAB</kbd> character with spaces.  (We cannot tell from here how many such characters were changed—perhaps, for instance, it replaced one <kbd>TAB</kbd> with four spaces, leaving four existing spaces in place, if you have everything rigged up to use columns 5, 9, 13, 17, and so on.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It is now time to avoid an entire separate aside on fixed vs variable pitch fonts. :-)

Comment: I still do not undertand how to fix my problem. I keep seeing this in git diff and reviewers keep bashing me. Anyone can help me fix the real problem?

Comment: @curiousengineer: there are several possible "real problem"s; which one you have depends on your environment (i.e., what your co-workers demand) and—crucially—the *solutions* to them *conflict with each other*, so first you're going to have to come to agreement with your co-workers on whether to use hard tabs at all, and if so, where to set them. The outcome of this conversation determines how to configure your editor.